# Case insensitive name/value map in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to have a @OneToMany relationship between an entity and a map of name/value pairs, where the map lookup is case insensitive.

I've found elements that can solve parts of my problem (String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, @SortComparator and so on), but I'm struggling to put it all together in a nice elegant fashion, so any help would be appreciated.

The code itself is rather simple

```
@Entity
public class Gizmo [

    private String name;

    private Map<String, GizmoData> data = new HashMap<String, GizmoData>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "gizmo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    public Map<String, GizmoData> getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getDataValue(String key) {
        GizmoData nvData = this.data.get(key);
        return (nvData != null ? nvData.getValue() : null);
    }

    public void setDataValue(String key, String value) {
        GizmoData nvData = new GizmoData(this, key, value);
        this.data.put(key, nvData);
    }
]


@Entity
public class GizmoData {

    private Gizmo gizmo;

    private String name;

    private String value;

    public GizmoData(Gizmo gizmo, String name, String value) {
        this.gizmo = gizmo;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "gizmoId", nullable = false)
    public Arrangement getGizmo() {
        return gizmo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I can obviously handle the case insensitive stuff in my transient method, to make sure all data inserted in code is manipulated (toLower() or something like that) and same with retrieving.

Problem is, there's another system that can insert data that I have no control of. And if that system inserts a NV pair with, say, camelCase, my getter needs to be able to retrieve it.

One solution is to create a TreeMap with the CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER comparator every time someone accesses the map, which strikes me as incredibly inefficient.

I've thought about maintaining a sorted map in parallel, using annotations like @PrePersist and @PreUpdate to sync up the map used by Hibernate, but that feels a bit clunky to say the least.

Ideally I'd want that one map controlled by Hibernate to be instantiated as a case insensitive one, but no idea how to do that. Is there a way to make "something like this" work?

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "gizmo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
@SortComparator(value String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```